# Can we worship Alakshmi?

Tags: identification-request, worship, alakshmi

I have heard that Alakshmi was worshipped at once. That's actually interesting and my doubt was arised from that.

So, my question is, can we worship Alakshmi? If yes, Which scripture say that/there any methods for worshipping her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alakṣmī is indeed worshipped by Bengalis.

While most Bengali Hindus observe the worship of *Dakṣiṇākālī* on the midnight of *Dīpānvitā amāvasyā*, families hailing from Eastern Bengal worship *Lakṣmī* on the evening of that day. Before commencing the worship of *Lakṣmī*, *Alakṣmī* is worshipped outside the courtyard on a heap of cowdung & she is asked to leave the household of the *yajamāna* and reside in that of the *yajamāna*'s enemies. *Alakṣmī*'s worship is ceremonially ended by women waving winnowing fans (used to separate chaff from grain), because it is believed that the wind arising out of a winnowing fan causes discomfort to *Alakṣmī*.

This *dhyānamantra* of *Alakṣmī* is traditionally employed by priests

> अलक्ष्मीं कृष्णवर्णाञ्च क्रोधनां कलहप्रियां । कृष्णवस्त्रपरिधानां लौहाभरणभूषितां ।। भग्नासनस्थां द्विभुजां शर्कराघृष्टचन्दनां । सम्मार्जनीसव्यहस्तां दक्षहस्तस्थशूर्पकां । तेलाभ्यङ्गितगात्राञ्च गर्दभारोहणां भजे ।।
>
> Translation: Worship *Alakṣmī*, who is of a dark complexion, angry disposition, fond of quarrels, wearing black clothes, decked in iron-made ornaments (in contrast to most other *devatā*s who wear ornaments made of gold), seated on a broken seat, bearing 2 arms, whose body is anointed with sugar-paste (in contrast to most other *devatā*s whoare anointed with sandalwood paste), holding the broom in the left hand & a winnowing fan in the right hand, whose body is anointed with oil & is seated on a donkey.

The worship is very brief & done with the left hand by black/blue coloured flowers.

*Skandapurāṇa* while describing the rites to be performed on this day, states

> एवं गते निशीथे च जने निद्रार्द्धलोचने । एवं नगरनारीभिः शूर्पडिण्डिमवादनैः । निष्कास्यते प्रदृष्टाभिरलक्ष्मीः स्वगृहाङ्गणात् ॥
>
> Translation: At the night (of *Dīpānvītā amāvasyā*) when people are half-asleep, *Alakṣmī* is driven out of the courtyards of houses by the womenfolk of the city by playing the winnowing fan & *ḍiṇḍima*. [*Skandapurāṇa*:*Vaiṣṇavakhaṇḍa*:*Kārtikamāsamāhātmya*:9:100]

Tamil Hindu women worship a *devī* called *Jyeṣṭhā* for marital bless. This *devī* is often called as *Jyeṣṭhalakṣmī*, is considered to be the elder sister of *Lakṣmī*, because she sprung before Her during churning of the ocean & is considered identical with *Alakṣmī*.